# Why this program works on an old Nano and doesn't work on Nano Every

Tags: arduino-nano

Can someone tell me why "XTronical graphical Pulse and Oxygen monitor Displays"
https://www.xtronical.com/colour-ecg-monitor/
works perfectly on an old Nano or an Uno and doesn't work on the new Nano Every 
even with Registers emulation: "ATMEGA328" ?

Is the Nano Every a "BAD BUY" ?

I very much welcome an explanation.
JFT

Comment: you need to explain in detail what you are talking about ... problem descriptions like `doesn't work` are meaningless

Comment: why would it be "bad buy"? because of some incompatible library you try to use?